# Methods of installing software in Ubuntu (command-line)

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I want to get information on **what are different methods to install** softwares/applications in Ubuntu (14.04)?

Example like :

- Install by `apt-get`
- Install from package-source or build-dependencies
- Compile from source
- Using binary package
- Install downloaded debs by `dpkg`

etc from my knowledge **but Give right & appropriate different methods**.

So, It can be knowledge base for new users to aware from different method and **when to use which**?

I am talking about different command-line methods rather than GUI or software-center because of knowledge-base and [package-management](/questions/tagged/package-management).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Yes [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/321954/256099) answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can install downloaded deb's through Ubuntu Software Center\Muon\etc. Almost always by double clicking in file manager, or

```
xdg-open <file>
```

You can build it from source with make and then, instead installing, use checkinstall to compile distribution package (deb\rpm\etc).

Answer (score 0):

Installing packages through `apt-get`,

```
 sudo apt-get install <package>
```

Installing packages through `aptitude`,

```
sudo aptitude install <package>
```

To install a .deb package through `dpkg`,

```
sudo dpkg -i file-name.deb
```

To install .deb packages through gdebi,

```
sudo gdebi file-name.deb
```

Installing packages through `apt`

```
sudo apt install <package>
```